# Capture network packets those are destined to a certain IP and Port and store them in a queue

Tags: c#, java, c

I would like to know how can I capture network packets those are destined to a certain IP and Port and store them in a queue before it reach to the application layer.And on later time depending on condition I want to dequeue the packets and send them to upper layer or destroy the packet. Is it possible in .NET framework using C# ?

Comment: You want to do it in .net and C#, but still tagged the question with Java and C? Those three languages, while somewhat similar (due to their common ancestry), are still three distinct and different languages.

Comment: And also, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Hmm... .Net is not really a language !

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks it seems like the OP is attempting to write a packet sniffer?

Answer (score 1):

You need a proxy to do that, which will act as "the man in the middle"

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (on a modern Linux system using virtuals) would be to configure iptables to reroute the packets to a different IP address (e.g. a 127.x.x.x address) write an application that captures / whatever those packets, and then resends them later on.  You probably need to run your real application in a virtual machine ... and do the iptable trickery in the virtual networking layer ... so that the real application can get the stuff by listening on the "real" IP address.

But it would be messy and complicated ... and potentially prone to dropping packets and VM stability nastiness.

Answer (score 0):

Just run ettercap or tcpdump. Then if you want you can use wireshark so inspect the packets, or if you are willing to, you can write your own program in any language you like to process that raw data.